# When paused and restarted, the countdown timer will not update in layout activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a pause button to work, currently it pauses the countdown timer, but when restarted the, countdownTextSeconds.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString(), does not update on the activity layout to show the current time counting down.

```
private fun roundOne() {
        val timerInterval = 60000L // the duration of the countdown in milliseconds
        val tickInterval = 1000L // the interval between countdown ticks in milliseconds

        countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timerInterval, tickInterval) {
            var isTextSpoken = false

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                if (!isPaused) {
                    countdownTextMovement.text = getString(R.string.swing_10_text)
                    countdownTextSeconds.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()

                    if (!isTextSpoken) {
                        isTextSpoken = true
                        textToSpeech.speak(
                            "Swing 10",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                    }
                    if (millisUntilFinished < 3000) {
                        val tone = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
                        tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 100)
                    }
                } else {
                    pauseTimeRemaining = millisUntilFinished
                }
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                countdownTimer?.cancel()
            }
        }
        countdownTimer?.start()

        binding.startTimerButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isPaused) {
                countdownTimer?.cancel()
                binding.startTimerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_24)
                isPaused = true
            } else {
                countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(pauseTimeRemaining, tickInterval) {


                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        countdownTextMovement.text = getString(R.string.swing_10_text)
                        countdownTextSeconds.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()

                        if (millisUntilFinished < 3000) {
                            val tone = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
                            tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 100)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {
                        (countdownTimer as CountDownTimer).cancel()
                    }
                }
                countdownTimer?.start()
                binding.startTimerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_24)
                isPaused = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `pauseTimeRemaining` is never set, once you cancel the timer in click, `onTick` is never triggered with `isPaused` as `true` hence it never goes to `else` block, to fix it you could just get rid of else and update `pauseTimeRemaining` on every `tick`

```
 countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timerInterval, tickInterval) {
            var isTextSpoken = false

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                if (!isPaused) {
                    countdownTextMovement.text = getString(R.string.swing_10_text)
                    countdownTextSeconds.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()

                    if (!isTextSpoken) {
                        isTextSpoken = true
                        textToSpeech.speak(
                            "Swing 10",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                    }
                    if (millisUntilFinished < 3000) {
                        val tone = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
                        tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 100)
                    }
                } 
                pauseTimeRemaining = millisUntilFinished
                
            }
```